# Bare error 500 in Laravel - tried everything

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

In a Vagrant Homestead environment (in Windows via VMware) I get the bare error 500 with some errors (e.g., forgotten "use") but normal Laravel debug error page with others (e.g., failing to define a route properly or failing to pass a variable to a blade template).

I have tried every solution I've found here and in searching, specifically:

- Reset permissions of storage dir (changed inside the VM and in Windows via git bash)
- Reset permissions of bootstrap/cache dir (changed inside the VM and in Windows via git bash)
- Cleared various cache directories
- Checked Laravel log (nothing in it about the failed event at all - which seems very odd)
- Checked nginx log (nothing in it about the failed event at all - which seems very odd)
- Checked FPM log (nothing in it about the failed event at all)
- Tried inserting my own exception code, per some people's posts, it never is executed/shown
- Tried inserting old error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); include("file_with_errors.php"); in a few different places per other posts -- nothing.
- Tried resetting the encryption key since someone said that might be an issue (why I don't know) -- nothing
- Tried reverting back to a backup of a week ago to undo symphony/etc. upgrades -- nothing
- Tried composer update -- nothing

  - Tried php artisan optimize -- nothing
- My APP_DEBUG setting is right (and again working appropriately on many errors just not certain ones, like missing "use")
- My project has ground to a halt because I can't debug even basic issues, and I'm out of ideas for what to try.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am stuck until I resolve this.

Comment: try echoing and exiting in `public/index.php` to see if at all laravel is being called.

Comment: I just tried that and it is dying within the:

 $response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

lines.

Comment: if the error is something which cannot be handled by laravel then it must be logged in webserver's log. Have you tried putting a `try-catch` around `$response = $kernel->handle( $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() );`?

Comment: I just tried wrapping that code in a try catch and though I don't immediately see how, it fails to catch the error and I just get the 500 message.  I re-inserted the die() statements to reconfirm where the code is dying and it really is in that section, and it really isn't catching the error.

Comment: then it should be logged in the webserver log.

Comment: I finally did find a location where the errors were being logged, thank goodness, the FPM log.  I had no idea FPM had its own log (I expected things like that to be in the nginx log).  

Something about my setup still seems wrong because I don't see why I'm not getting a sophisticated Whoops-ish Laravel error page in those cases (missing Use), but I do in other cases (blade error).  Maybe that's just how Laravel is, I'm relatively new to it, and certainly to 5.3.